# Dúvida com rota

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou há um tempo tentando fazer uma rota funcionar, mas até agora nada...

Controller:

```
public function profissionais(Request $request, $id){
    $vinculo = session()->get('vinculo');

    $profissionais = Vinculo::where('unidade_id', '=', $id)->get();

    $unidades = Unidade::where('municipio_id', '=', $vinculo->usuario->municipio_id)
                        ->get();

    $profissionais = $id;

    return view('relatorios.profissionais', compact('unidades', 'profissionais'));
}
```

Formulário:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{route('relatorios.profissionais', 'id')}}">
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="id" required>
        @foreach($unidades as $unidade)
            <option value="{{$unidade->id}}">{{$unidade->descricao}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Listar</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/relatorios/profissionais/{id}', 'RelatorioController@profissionais')->name('relatorios.profissionais');
```

Já tentei de toda forma, mas vi que ainda não entendi a lógica no sistema...

O que quero é que a url apareça assim: `/relatorios/profissionais/4` e o controller receba o número 4 na variável `$id` e busque os vínculos.

Mas no momento a url está sendo mostrada assim: `relatorios/profissionais/id?id=4`

Comment: O segundo parametro do metodo route que está no attr action do form deve ser um id (numeral). 4 ou '4' 

{{route('relatorios.profissionais', 4)}}

Mas mesmo assim não da pra entender... Acho que precisava ver teu javascript pra isso.

Talvez colocar a rota dentro do foreach, no attr value de cada option... Então no evento change do select tu troca o attributo action do form.

<option value="{{route('relatorios.profissionais', $unidade->id)}}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu vou te dar duas opções, escolha a que for conveniente.

## Primeira opção

Em vez de passar o valor na rota assim `{id}`, você pode usar os [query strings](https://www.portaleducacao.com.br/conteudo/artigos/informatica/definindo-uma-query-string/38127).
Então na sua rota, você elinaria o `{id}` assim:

```
Route::get('/relatorios/profissionais', 'RelatorioController@profissionais')->name('relatorios.profissionais');
```

E no seu Controller, você eliminaria o parâmetro `$id` e pegaria o valor do `id` pela `request`, ficando:

```
public function profissionais(Request $request){
    $id = $request->query('id');
```

Por fim, na sua view, você eliminaria da função `route` no `action` o seu segundo parâmetro, ficando apenas:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{route('relatorios.profissionais')}}">
```

Documentação da função `query` você encontra [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input).

---

## Segunda opção

Você teria que usar Javascript para obter o valor selecionado do `<select/>`, seria mais ou menos algo como isso:

```
// Seu action não estaria mais definido aqui.
<form id="form_unidade" method="GET" onclick="submitForm()">
    <select id="select_unidade" class="js-example-basic-single" name="id" required>
...

// Mas seria atribuido o action aqui.
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(){
    var e = document.getElementById("select_unidade");
    var unidade_id = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    $("#form_unidade").attr("action", "www.seusite.com/relatorios/profissionais/" + unidade_id);
    $("#form_unidade").submit();
 }
 </script>
```

Caso queira saber mais sobre o código acima, eu me basei nesse [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) e [nesse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979024/changing-the-action-of-a-form-with-javascript-jquery/3863869#3863869).
Sugiro também dar uma olhada em [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding), o que simplificaria ainda mais seu código se você usasse com a solução acima.

Ps: acredito que a solução acima necessitária do JQuery também.